# ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. Issue with importing ultralytics YoloV8

Tags: opencv, aws-lambda, dockerfile, yolov8, aws-lambda-containers

I have a docker image that is a lambda function that I generated and stored on Amazon ECR. However when running it, I encounter this error.
'[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'

I believe this is because I installed the ultralytics package. I'm using YoloV8 for a model. I saw in [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/370) post that it was because I wasn't using opencv-python-headless. How would I configure ultralytics to use this package?

I've tried increasing the memory, which solved an error of [import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPKxO.png). Could someone explain why this occurred. It went away when I doubled the memory so I assume it was a lack of memory in the environment?